# Issue getting Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to override MessageSource values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I have spring Java config object that loads my properties but does not override the MessageSource tokens.

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class PropertyConfiguration {

public static final String PROPERTY_OVERRIDE_URL = "d2.config.location";

@Bean
public UrlResource propertyOverrideUrl() {
    String propertyOverrideUrl = System.getProperty(PROPERTY_OVERRIDE_URL);

    UrlResource overrideUrl = null;
    // just add a bogus url as to not get a malformed URL
    try{
        overrideUrl = new UrlResource(
                (propertyOverrideUrl == null || "".equals(propertyOverrideUrl)? "file:///FILENOTFOUND" : propertyOverrideUrl)
        );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        // Set the URL to a dummy value so it will not break.
        try{
            overrideUrl = new UrlResource("file:///FILENOTFOUND");
        } catch (MalformedURLException me){
            // this is a valid URL, but will not be found at runtime.
        }
    }
    return overrideUrl;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("propertyOverrideUrl")
@Lazy(false)
public ContextAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
throws IOException{
    return new ContextAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(){{
        setLocations(new Resource[]{
            new ClassPathResource("application_prompts.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("application_webservice.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("application_externalApps.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("application_log4j.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("application_fileupload.properties"),
            //Must be last to override all other resources
            propertyOverrideUrl()
        });
        setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    }};
}
```

When I run a unit test on the javaconfig property it is fine:

```
    @Test
public void testOverrides__Found() throws Exception {
    setOverrideUrlSystemProperty("/target/test/resources/override-test.properties");
    context = SpringContextConfigurationTestHelper.createContext();
    context.refresh();

    String recordedPaymentConfirmationPath =
            (String)context.getBean("recordedPaymentConfirmationPath");
    assertThat(recordedPaymentConfirmationPath, is("test/dir/recordings/"));

    String promptServerUrl =
            (String)context.getBean("promptServerUrl");
    assertThat(promptServerUrl, is("http://test.url.com"));
}
```

But when I try the value of the MessageSource, it still has the old value:

```
    @Test
public void testOverrides__XYZ() throws Exception {
    setOverrideUrlSystemProperty("/target/test/resources/override-test.properties");
    context = SpringContextConfigurationTestHelper.createContext();
    context.refresh();

    String promptServerUrl = (String)context.getMessage("uivr.prompt.server.url",
                    new Object[] {}, Locale.US);

    assertThat(promptServerUrl, is("http://test.url.com"));
}
```

The output:

```
[junit] Testcase: testOverrides__XYZ took 0.984 sec
[junit]     FAILED
[junit]
[junit] Expected: is "http://test.url.com"
[junit]      got: "http://24.40.46.66:9010/agent-ivr-prompts/"
[junit]
[junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
[junit] Expected: is "http://test.url.com"
[junit]      got: "http://24.40.46.66:9010/agent-ivr-prompts/"
[junit]
[junit]     at     com.comcast.ivr.agent.configuration.PropertyOverrideConfigurationTest.testOverrides__XYZ(PropertyOverrideConfigurationTest.java:114)
```

Can someone please help me find a way to override the MessageSource because that is what is used in our velocity templates:

```
    #set($baseUrl = "#springMessage('uivr.prompt.server.url')")
```

I added some logging:

```
  @Override
  protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {
    super.loadProperties(props);
    super.mergeProperties();
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        for (Map.Entry entry : props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
            logger.info(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }
}
```

And the values are printed as expected.

```
...
[junit] uivr.prompt.server.url:http://test.url.com
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple side notes about the annotations used on your `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer()` `@Bean` method:

- @`Lazy(false)` is unnecessary, as it is already the default.  You can omit this.
- `@DependsOn("propertyOverrideUrl")` is unnecessary, because the dependency is already established by calling `propertyOverrideUrl()` from within the `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer()`

On to your actual question, it's a bit tough to answer because I'm not sure what `ContextAwareProperyPlaceholderConfigurer` does (I'm assuming it's a custom component as it's not part of the core Spring Framework).

That aside, there may simply be a misunderstanding going on.  Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (PPC) and friends operate by post-processing bean definitions to replace `${...}` placeholders, but don't interact with `MessageSource` objects in any way.  So the behavior you describe is, I believe, as expected:  You would see the 'correct' URL when interrogating the bean (because it has been post-processed by your PPC), however you see the 'incorrect' url when interrogating the message source (because it is totally unrelated to PPC post-processing).

Hope this helps.